# How to get the normal theme uri when using WP_CONTENT_URL?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress install and I'm using a cookieless domain for all my resources. One of those resources is an svg sprite file that I'm referencing using the `<svg><use>` tags.

This creates a problem whereby I can't use the static domain as this breaks the `<svg><use>` in many browsers due to a limitation placed on domains.

So all I need to do is get the normal uri for example( http://example.com/wp-content/theme/image/ ) but what I currently get is( http://static.example.com/wp-content/theme/image/ )

How can I get the normal domain based theme uri?

Answer (score 0):

On which domain is your site running? The URL to your theme can be found using

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
```

Comment: This also returns the static domain

Comment: Can I assume you run your website on static.example.com then?

Comment: The website runs on http://example.com however using the WP_CONTENT_URL feature wordpress gets all media files from http://static.example.com, this static domain is created and assigned to the wp-content folder of the wordpress install. This creates a cookieless based domain for all static assets to be pulled from. Im doing this to boost performance scores on tools like pingdom.